# using membership provider for a small website in MVC3 or to implement Iprincipal?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

im building a new project in mvc 3 on MySql
i managed to make the membership work on MySql and use the login form that comes as default when creating a new mvc 3 application.
but...
i wanted to add more fields to the registration page like "sex" and "state"
i read that i should use the profilebase in order to do that.
but i had no luck with it..

my question is:
would you use the all membership provider for a small site?

or is it better to just implement Iprincipal on your own and create this kind of registration and login. with only one table in the database of "users"
so is membership provider out of the box is a bit overhead for a small project?

i didn't find a good example for creating a basic registration form and login form in mvc 3
without the membership provider

would like to hear your opinion

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some answers which might help you decide.

1. [Should I use the built-in membership provider for an ASP .NET MVC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301541/should-i-use-the-built-in-membership-provider-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)
2. [How do you get the UserID of a User object in ASP.Net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924692/how-do-you-get-the-userid-of-a-user-object-in-asp-net-mvc)
3. [How to create a asp.net membership provider hashed password manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547397/how-to-create-a-asp-net-membership-provider-hashed-password-manually)

#### UPDATE

An example for creating a custom registration and login? Possibly. [Here's an example of creating](https://github.com/PureKrome/RavenOverflow/tree/master/Code/RavenOverflow.Web/Models/Authentication) a [custom Provider](https://github.com/PureKrome/RavenOverflow/blob/master/Code/RavenOverflow.Web/Models/Authentication/CustomPrincipal.cs) and [Identity](https://github.com/PureKrome/RavenOverflow/blob/master/Code/RavenOverflow.Web/Models/Authentication/ICustomIdentity.cs) ... and using Facebook to handle the username/password credentials. [Even though this project](https://github.com/PureKrome/RavenOverflow) uses RavenDb as the database, it's a 1 second job to swap that out and use EF/L2S/NHibernate, etc... or even a normal forms auth where you ask for a username / password.

Comment: i liked the first link to that answer you gave there..
but do you know of an example for creating a custom registration and login without the use of membership provider? thanks

Comment: Updated my answer to include a possible sample provider.